# SegFault/Abort when using scanf to read large strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

I noticed that when reading a string using scanf in C, it is possible for a string to exceed the amount of characters allocated to it. When this happens I usually encounter a segmentation fault or abort. I've made a quick demo below.

```
char string[50];

scanf("%s", string);
string[49] = '\0';
```

Now, if a user were to enter something longer than 50 chars, the code would crash. I tried solving this by adding `string[49] = '\0'` however that does not seem to be fixing the problem. I understand there is an alternative with `fgets`, however I do not want the user to be able to write spaces.

Comment: you can use `scanf("%49s", string);` for only reading 49 characters, this also ends the string with '\0'

Comment: Off by 1: "if a user were to enter something longer than 49 chars ...".

Comment: "I do not want the user to be able to write spaces." --> Use `fgets()` and then parse the data from the string.

Comment: This all comes down to user input is evil.  How do you want to handle a user entering more than N characters?  How about inputs like `"\n"`, `" \n"`, `" leading_trailing_space \n"`,  `"in between space\n"`, `" "`? If code does not handle challenging cases well, I hope the user base is trustworthy - else code becomes buggy or a hacker target.  Recommenced to stay with `fgets()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the size of string read in within `scanf` itself like so

```
scanf("%49s", string);
```

Comment: From @User9123 : "however I do not want the user to be able to write spaces" ? How this solution can prevent/manage this ?

Comment: @Landstalker the `%s` format doesn't read in spaces - specifying a width doesn't change that

Comment: ok, but if i enter "12 34", what happend for the part "34" ? (the blanc between 2 and 3 is a space) you will probably lose it...

Comment: @Landstalker the " 34" will stay in the buffer until it is read in or will be lost when the program terminates

Comment: Ok, but if you call : `strlen, printf` ... on the variable `string` (readed with `scanf("%49s", string);` ) you will have results depending on the content of the string (12) and not on the content that remained in the buffer (truncated  part "34"). and this may distort the behavior of the program

Comment: @Landstalker what remains in the buffer isn't important and won't affect the program as all it is doing is reading in a single string

Comment: Ok, if we assume that what is entered after the space character can be ignored

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have two constraints: the size of the string and the content of the string (space character not desired).

I think you have to process the characters one by one in something that looks like this:

In the define part:

```
#define MAX_CHAR 50
```

In the code part:

```
char chr;
int  iNbRead = 0;
char string[MAX_CHAR]="";

while ( ((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n') && (iNbRead < MAX_CHAR-1))
{
    if (chr == ' ') 
    {
      // do something for space : for example by ignoring it ...
    }
    else
       string[iNbRead++] = chr;
}
```

You will have control over both the number of characters entered and the content of the characters entered